# Meteor iron:router this.render() is blocking in onBeforeAction-hook

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

So I've been searching for a solution for hours now, but can't seem to figure it out myself.
I have iron:router onBeforeAction-hooks setup to check for different permissions, for example if the user is logged in. However, once the permission check fails, and this.render(..) is called, im stuck on that template until I reload the page - clicking a link to another route is not enough.

```
var onBeforeActions = {
    loginRequired: function() {
        if(Meteor.loggingIn() || !this.ready()) {
            return this.render('loading');
        } else if(!Meteor.user()) {
            return this.render('accessDenied');
        }
        return this.next();
    },
...
Router.onBeforeAction(onBeforeActions.loginRequired, {
    only: ['postSubmit', 'postSubmitHandhistory', 'postEdit', 'postPage', 'groupJoin', 'groupPage', 'groupEdit'],
});
```

So, for example, I am on a restricted page, click "logout" and "login" again. Then im stuck with the loading-template forever, until I hit F5.
I can see that the routes change, cause I can see that the data-context changes, but the yield-layout is not reloaded.
I also checked that the onBeforeAction is rerun, and in fact it is, it even reaches the

```
this.next();
```

But it's not rerendering.. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

Okay I finally found the solution to my problem. It seems like there wasn't anything wrong with the router, but instead I had a bug in my page transitions, which somehow prevented the old layouts from being removed.